# Is the comparison between absolute values of ∆S and ∆H for a given reaction meaningful?

Tags: thermodynamics

How do you know if the reaction is dominated by enthalpic or entropic factor? Do you just compare the absolute values of them? If the absolute value of ∆S is bigger than the absolute value of ∆H, can you conclude that the entropy is a more potent factor in determining the reaction progression?

Comment: You cannot compare the values of ∆H and ∆S, because they don't have the same unit. The first is in Joule and the second in Joule/Kelvin

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the change in Gibbs Free Energy: ∆G = ∆H - T∆S. Reaction is spontaneous if ∆G < 0.

You can see from this equation that knowledge of ∆H and ∆S without T is insufficient. For example, close to absolute zero ∆H dominates even if ∆S is large because T x ∆S will be very small.

Important Caveat: ∆G is only useful if temperature and pressure are constant. If the process involves a change in T or P, then ∆G cannot tell us if the reaction will be spontaneous.

Comment: Better to say that final T and p must be the same as initial ones. They can change during the reaction.

Comment: Delta G is useful with change in T and P The change in Keq is a known function of Delta H. Knowing Keq at a T enables determining spontaneity at a given set of reaction conditions. A more holistic view is that Delta G for a given set of conditions is a function of temperature depending on Delta H and Delta S and becoming zero when those conditions satisfy the equilibrium constant at the appropriate temperature.